# Angular 5 chart.js onclick returning empty array

Tags: angular, chart.js

I'm trying to get the onclick function in chart.js to work, and found out about the `getElementsAtEvent(event)` function that should return an array containing the data of the part of the chart that I click, but it's constantly returning an empty array.

Here's my code:

```
var canvas = this.el; //this is an elementref
canvas.onclick = (event) => {
  var data = this.chart.getElementsAtEvent(event)
  console.log(data);
}

this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Browser", "Game", "Word Processing", "Database", "Spreadsheet", "Multimedia"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'number of applications related to',
      data: [24, 10, 30, 20, 46, 78],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2',
      borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'red',
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      text: "Application Logs",
      display: true
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

Not sure if this is part of why it doesn't work but here's my canvas:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="123" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas>
```

Like I mentioned it just prints out an empty array [] in the console, and using `console.log(data[0])` obviously just returns undefined.

Comment: check my answer it should solve your issue.

Comment: I have added a demo link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below code works for me, and also it's not required to use `ElementRef` to add the click event handler. You can just call a method on the `(click)` event of the `<canvas>` like below -

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="123" #mychart (click)="showData($event)" class="chartjs-render-monitor">{{chart}}</canvas>
```

Here I have rendered the chart using the `chart` property of the component.

Here is the `showData()` method -

```
showData(evt:any){
  var data = this.chart.getElementsAtEvent(evt)
  console.log(data[0]._model); // it prints the value of the property
}
```

Here is the complete working code -

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component,ViewChild,ElementRef,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Chart from 'chart.js';
declare var Chart: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit{
  name = 'Angular 5';
  chart:any;
  // @ViewChild('mychart') el:ElementRef; 

  constructor(){

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.createChart();
  }
createChart(){
// var canvas = this.el; 

this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Browser", "Game", "Word Processing", "Database", "Spreadsheet", "Multimedia"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'number of applications related to',
      data: [24, 10, 30, 20, 46, 78],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2',
      borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'red',
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      text: "Application Logs",
      display: true
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
})
}
    showData(evt:any){
      var data = this.chart.getElementsAtEvent(evt)
      console.log(data[0]._model);
     }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="123" #mychart (click)="showData($event)" class="chartjs-render-monitor">{{chart}}</canvas>
```

Here is a working  demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-example-txcthz